# How to deal with a dependency cycle between several related classes?

Tags: php, oop

Let's say I have a group of database tables (customer, product, category, customer_products, product_categories, customer_categories) and classes corresponding to each of them (basic entity classes for the basic entity tables, and classes like CustomerProductLinker for the foreign key tables). The "linker" classes have methods like addXToY, removeXFromY, getXsOfY, and getYsOfX.

The problem comes from the additional business requirements that 1) adding a Customer to a Product should add that Customer to each of the Product's Categories, and 2) adding a Product to a Category should add each of that Product's Customers to the Category. With the current class system, that creates a dependency cycle between CustomerProductLinker and ProductCategoryLinker.

I do not know how to solve this. Combining all the "linkers" into one big "SuperLinker" class seems very wrong. And keeping the linker object instantiation inside only the methods that need them rather than passing the linkers in via constructor injection seems worse (though it would *technically* solve the cycle).

I doubt this system of linker classes is the best way to handle this kind of setup, but I'm not experienced enough to know what could be done instead. Unfortunately **I can't use an ORM, because the tables are not all stored on the same server.** So... What else can be done?

Comment: I usually hate these responses but there are a ton of ORM frameworks out there to handle this kind of thing. In this case reinventing the wheel does not seem to be the best strategy.

Comment: I think that the mistake is that you are not creating proper associations. You should not add a customer to each of the product categories, but to the product itself. Then retrieve the customer categories somehow like this: $customer->getProduct()->getCategories().

Comment: I would use an ORM if I could, but the tables aren't all stored on the same server.